# Jetty WebSocketException can not call method

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, java-websocket

I am trying to use websockets in java and I am coming across this issue:

```
Cannot call method public final void package.ClientWebSocket#jettyOnMessage(byte[], int, int) with args: [[B, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer]
```

Here is the code snippet that is actually being called

```
 @OnWebSocketMessage
 public final void jettyOnMessage(final byte[] data, final int offset, final int length) {
     onMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(data, offset, length));
 }
```

Here is there documentation that describes what the method signature should be:

```
 * <u>Binary Message Versions</u>
 * <ol>
 * <li><code>public void methodName(byte buf[], int offset, int length)</code></li>
 * <li><code>public void methodName({@link Session} session, byte buf[], int offset, int length)</code></li>
 * <li><code>public void methodName(InputStream stream)</code></li>
 * <li><code>public void methodName({@link Session} session, InputStream stream)</code></li>
 * </ol>
 */
```

As you can tell I am using the first version of the call.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit1:

I made the method non final and that did not change anything.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the issue if anyone gets a similar exception.

The issue is that internally one of my methods throw an uncaught exception.

If you wrap your entire code in a try you can avoid this exception completely and find the real reason it is getting thrown.

Code that fixed issue:

```
@OnWebSocketMessage
public final void jettyOnMessage(final byte[] data, final int offset, final int length) {
    try {
        onMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(data, offset, length));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where the onMessage can possibly throw an exception

Im my case it ended up being an ArrayOutOfBoundsException because I was stupidly doing list.get(list.size());

Its the little things that get you.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?  I would love to make that error message more clear in a future version of Jetty.

Comment: I edited the answer to show my actual solution code but I think it depends on how you are calling the method.  If you are using reflection then I think this will solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049749/java-reflection-and-checked-exceptions

This post from a different person appeared to find a way to show the cause
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549072/exception-using-jetty-websocket-while-trying-to-parse-received-messages

Comment: Also I am using jetty-all (from maven) version 9.2.2.v20140723

Comment: Created Jetty bug to track this ... https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457017